# Python - how do I highlight period between two dates on a chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a times series and I want to highlight period between two dates with some color what's the best way to do that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,50),columns=['A'],index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods=50,freq='D'))
```

Assuming that I want to highlight the period between 13th Jan and 13th Feb.

I want something similar to what's shows in this chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plot a **bar** on same axis with suitable parameters

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,50),columns=['A'],index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01',periods=50,freq='D'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=[14,4])
df.plot(ax=ax)

mask = (df.index >= "13-Jan-2020") & (df.index<="13-Feb-2020")
df.loc[mask,["bar"]] = df.A.max()
ax.bar(df.index, df.bar, zorder=0, width=1, alpha=.5)
```

[image]